# Register remote Weblogic to Netbeans

Tags: java, netbeans, weblogic

I know I can register a `remote` `Weblogic` server with **JDeveloper** and **Eclipse** but I can't figure out how to do that with `Netbeans`.

I have searched through Internet and I can't get a clear answer. Is this functionality supported or not?

Comment: Are you trying to do something other than: http://wiki.netbeans.org/FaqDebuggingRemote ?

Comment: Both what you are describing and also start/stop the server check the applications/beans that are deployed etc. In general have the same functionality as working with a local weblogic server. Also the link you posted says: Applies to: NetBeans 5.x, 6.x what about Netbeans 8.x

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was browsing at NetBeans roadmap and accidentally found:[Remote_WebLogic](http://wiki.netbeans.org/NewAndNoteworthyNB81#Remote_WebLogic)

Which means that development support for ***remote*** Weblogic server will be available when Netbeans 8.1 comes out.

Comment: Too bad it still requires you to have WebLogic installed locally (guess it needs some of the libraries from the installation). So updating to 8.1 from 8.0.1 was a bust. Guess I'll have to write my own plugin to manage remote WL instances.